# Help with Edge creases, creat folds in corners

Tags: edges

I'm trying to make an engine sit ontop of a wing for my spaceship. However, When I don't use edge creases, I get circles.. when I do I get folds in the mesh.

here is the Un-sub-D modded mesh:
[image]

this is what it looks like with the sub-division modifier:
[image]

once I add the additional lines.. like this:
[image]

I end up having corner folds, which suck...
[image]
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like the geometry may not be manifold, or normals may be incorrect. Is this a possibility?

Comment: I checked that all good

Comment: Hmm. Degenerate geometry?

Comment: I can give it a try